# Using GPS, How can i detect if user on road or inside a building

Tags: gps

I am currently developing technique to help users find a spot to park.
But i face a little problem:
if a user indicates that he is parking right now in a free spot but he is lying and he is at home right now.
How can i detect from GPS if he is inside a building or along side the road?
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to approach the problem by removing incentives for intentionally false reporting?  Unless differential GPS is engaged, I would think accuracy of location reported is not sufficient to address your question.  On the other hand, high velocity may give you a degree of insight.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need map data (OpenStreetMap is free), and figure out whether the user is somewhere on that map or not. You do that by comparing GPS data to the map data.

What I do in such situations is measure the distance between the lat/lon and each road, and compare the GPS angle to that of each line. The more context information you use the more accurate you can get your results:

- If the speed is 60km/h, you're probably not in a building. You're probably not on a 30km/h road either.
- If you're standing still for more than 2 minutes, you're probably not in a car.
- If you know the buildings, and there are only a few of them, you could check if you see a certain wifi router or not.

Basically you'll calculate a score for each road, and then pick the road with the highest score to know where you are.

Score = DistScore*DistWeight + AngleScore+AngleWeight etc.

Also, from iOS and Android you get an accuracy in meters. You can also calculate that yourself if you can access raw GPS data. Using that, you set the area that you need to scan. For example, for a high accuracy (3m), you probably don't have many roads to scan. If the accuracy is 50m, you should probably match roads that are farther away.

If accuracy is important, you should look at series of GPS data, and test if the followed route is a logical path or not.

Comment: Not bad answer, since I work in the same field, Did you work on professional projects related to such map matching? If yes for which country project?